# Config React.js route to run next.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, frontend

I already have a react app, I want to make a particular route in react app as separate next.js app for SEO.

please can you tell me how to do or where to start from

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi  
> You can take the Next.js incremental adoption approach. You may find these two pages helpful: 1. https://nextjs.org/blog/incremental-adoption 2. https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/incremental-adoption

ref: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/29228#discussioncomment-1358416